# React Native Webview: Browser not supported

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I'm playing around with react-native-webview, and when I tried to add this URL (https://maps.flydenver.com/) I received this error:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
            backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'
            barStyle='dark-content'/>
            <WebView
                source={{uri: 'https://maps.flydenver.com/'}}
                scalesPageToFit = {false}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}

                />
        </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think version issue.**

npm i --save react-native-webview@7.5.0

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'www.google.com'}}
/>
```